# Assigning first row to be column names of a data frame

Tags: r

I'm trying to assign the first row of a data frame to be the  colnames, my data frames are dynamically named i.e like "frame_1" "frame_2" e.t.c

Am doing this by:

```
for( i in 1:length(holder)){
  colnames(eval( parse(text=paste0("frame_",i))) )<- eval( parse(text=paste0("frame_",i,"[1,]")))
}
```

However this is producing the mysterious error:

```
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I find this confusing given that:

```
colnames(eval( parse(text=paste0("frame_",i))) )
```

Produces the vector of colnames for frame_i

```
eval( parse(text=paste0("frame_",i,"[1,]")))
```

Produces the first row of frame_i.

Both of these are the same length, if anyone can explain this error to me I will be very grateful

Some code to produce a similar dataset to mine:

```
for( i in 1:1000){
assign(paste("frame",i,sep="_"), data.frame(  c("desired_colname", 4, 3, 5, 7) , c("desired_colname2", 3, 1, 2, 3) )) }
```

So I want to put "desired_colname" as the column name.

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example please.

Comment: @RichardScriven No that is not the case. 
I will write some code to produce reproducible data for you.

Comment: @user1987097 Have you tried the code below?

Comment: its broken a bunch of the data frames, when I try to view them its returning error "Error in View : undefined columns selected
"

Comment: @user1987097 Not on the example I created though.

Comment: @akrun Not one? It's broken 80% of the frames I have and the other ones have what I want done to them

Comment: @user1987097 Could you show the dput output of some of your datasets i.e. `dput(head(frame_1))` `dput(head(frame_2))`

Comment: The colnames are the usual placeholders i.e X.1 X.2 X.3, the first row is full of strings, then the data starts on the next row.

Comment: @user1987097 The example you showed works fine. Please check the update

Comment: @user1987097 I don't really understand these operations.  If the first row needs to be colname, it would have been easier with using `read.table` and specifying `header=TRUE` or if you want to skip a row, you can also use `skip=1`.  At present, this looks like not the optimal way because your columns are `characters` or `factors` and you need to delete the first row and then change them to numeric class.

Comment: @akrun I've had to do some processing on the data already to get it in the form discussed here.

Comment: @user1987097 But, from the example you showed, it seems like this would have been solved by `read.table`.

Comment: The frames form I'm presenting, I have had to make out of another, single object.

Comment: @user1987097 Anyway, I can't reproduce the error you got from the same set of dataset you showed.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
frame_1 <-  data.frame(c("desired_colname", 4, 3, 5, 7) , 
                                 c("desired_colname2", 3, 1, 2, 3) )
frame_2 <-  data.frame( c("desired_colname", 4, 2, 6, 7) ,
                             c("desired_colname2", 3, 5, 3, 3) )
frame_3 <-  data.frame(c("desired_colname", 5, 6, 9, 5) ,
                             c("desired_colname2", 5, 9, 14, 3) )


holder <- ls(pattern="^frame_")

for(i in holder){
 tmp <- get(i)
 colnames(tmp) <- unlist(get(i)[1,])
 assign(i, tmp)
}
```

The above code could be also written as:

```
  for(i in holder){
    assign(i, `names<-`(get(i), unlist(get(i)[1,])))
   }


 frame_1
#  desired_colname desired_colname2
#1 desired_colname desired_colname2
#2               4                3
#3               3                1
#4               5                2
#5               7                3


 frame_2
 # desired_colname desired_colname2
 #1 desired_colname desired_colname2
 #2               4                3
 #3               2                5
 #4               6                3
 #5               7                3
```

Another option would be to use `list2env`

```
   list2env(lapply(mget(holder), function(x)
           {colnames(x) <- unlist(x[1,]);x}), envir=.GlobalEnv)
   #<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Though, all these operations could be done within a `list` and then use `write.table` to save it in file.